# FB.login not asking for permissions

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to integrate FB login with my html website. I am using FB Javascript SDK version 2.5. The pop-up opens and ask the users for the userid and password but donnot ask for permissions like email, public profile, location etc although i have given the required permissions in the scope param. Below is my code.

HTML code:

```
<div id="btnFBLogin"> <img style="width: 35%"
                                        src="assets/img/icons/facebookloginbutton.png" />
</div>
```

Initializing FB Javascript SDK and gets initialized on document load :

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : 'XXXXXXXXX',
          xfbml      : true,
          oauth      : true,
          version    : 'v2.5'
        });
      };

        //Load SDK  

         (function(d, s, id){
             var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
             if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
             js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
             js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
             fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
           }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

Calling FB.login api:

```
$('#btnFBLogin').on('click',function(){

          FB.login(function(response) {

              console.log(JSON.stringify(response));


              if (response.status === 'connected') {
                  // Logged into your app and Facebook.

FB.api('/me', function(response) {
            console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        });

                } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
                  // The person is logged into Facebook, but not your app.
                  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                    'into this app.';
                } else {

                  document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
                    'into Facebook.';
                }

         }, {scope: 'public_profile,email'});

      });
```

The response object returned after login by FB.api('/me', function(response) gives only full name of the user logged in. It doesn't give me the email id although i have send it in the scope parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to pass requested fields in url like

```
  FB.api('/me?fields=id,first_name,last_name,friends,email',function(response)
```